# Pausing / Resuming Screen recording with Windows Graphics Capture API

Tags: c#, screen-capture, direct3d11, screen-recording, windows-graphics-capture

I am building a screen recording app in C# using [Windows Graphics Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture?view=winrt-22621) API. I am using [this script](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/SimpleRecorder/). I can select monitor and can record it to mp4 file. I am trying to add Pause/Resume functionality.

Here is code of **main Window** that initiates Recording

```
try
{
    newFile = GetTempFile();
    using (var stream = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.CreateNew).AsRandomAccessStream())
    using (_encoder = new Encoder(_device, item))
    {
        await _encoder.EncodeAsync(
            stream,
            width, height, bitrate,
            frameRate);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  //
}
```

And here is the main function from **Encoder class**, which is used above

```
private async Task EncodeInternalAsync(IRandomAccessStream stream, uint width, uint height, uint bitrateInBps, uint frameRate)
{
    if (!_isRecording)
    {
        _isRecording = true;

        _frameGenerator = new CaptureFrameWait(
            _device,
            _captureItem,
            _captureItem.Size);

        using (_frameGenerator)
        {
            var encodingProfile = new MediaEncodingProfile();
            encodingProfile.Container.Subtype = "MPEG4";
            encodingProfile.Video.Subtype = "H264";
            encodingProfile.Video.Width = width;
            encodingProfile.Video.Height = height;
            encodingProfile.Video.Bitrate = bitrateInBps;
            encodingProfile.Video.FrameRate.Numerator = frameRate;
            encodingProfile.Video.FrameRate.Denominator = 1;
            encodingProfile.Video.PixelAspectRatio.Numerator = 1;
            encodingProfile.Video.PixelAspectRatio.Denominator = 1;
            var transcode = await _transcoder.PrepareMediaStreamSourceTranscodeAsync(_mediaStreamSource, stream, encodingProfile);

            await transcode.TranscodeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally this is the initializer function in **CaptureFrameWait** class

```
private void InitializeCapture(SizeInt32 size)
{
    _framePool = Direct3D11CaptureFramePool.CreateFreeThreaded(
        _device,
        DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized,
        1,
        size);
    _framePool.FrameArrived += OnFrameArrived;
    _session = _framePool.CreateCaptureSession(_item);
    _session.IsBorderRequired = false;
    _session.StartCapture();
}
```

How can we modify this to pause the recording? I have tried to dispose the **_framepool** and **_session** objects on Pause and initialize them again on Resume in **CaptureFrameWait** class, like shown below. It works fine, but sometimes TranscodeAsync function terminates during pause and ends recording. How can we avoid that?

```
bool _paused = false;
public void PauseSession(bool status)
{
    if (status) {
        _paused = true;
        _framePool?.Dispose();
        _session?.Dispose();
    }
    else {
        InitializeCapture(_size);
        _paused = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: One solution is when paused to just send the same timeStamp again and again. Another solution is to call `var def = args.Request.GetDeferral()` in `OnMediaStreamSourceSampleRequested` when asked for paused, and give back a sample and call `def.Complete()` once resumed.

Comment: @SimonMourier thank you for your suggestion. This seems to be working well. Please post this as an answer so I can accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to [get a deferral](https://MediaStreamSourceSampleRequest.GetDeferral%20Method). Doc says:

> The MediaStreamSource will then wait for you to supply the
> MediaStreamSample until you mark the deferral as complete.

So for example, add two private members to the `Encoder` class and two methods:

```
private MediaStreamSourceSampleRequestedEventArgs _args;
private MediaStreamSourceSampleRequestDeferral _def;

public bool IsPaused { get; private set; }

public void Pause()
{
    IsPaused = true;
}

public void Resume()
{
    IsPaused = false;

    // complete the request we saved earlier
    OnMediaStreamSourceSampleRequested(_mediaStreamSource, _args);
}
```

And modify `OnMediaStreamSourceSampleRequested` methods like this (where I've put comments):

```
private void OnMediaStreamSourceSampleRequested(MediaStreamSource sender, MediaStreamSourceSampleRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    if (_isRecording && !_closed)
    {
        // if paused get a deferral and save the current arguments.
        // OnMediaStreamSourceSampleRequested will not be called again until we complete the deferral
        if (IsPaused)
        {
            _def = args.Request.GetDeferral();
            _args = args;
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            using (var frame = _frameGenerator.WaitForNewFrame())
            {
                if (frame == null)
                {
                    args.Request.Sample = null;
                    DisposeInternal();
                    return;
                }

                var timeStamp = frame.SystemRelativeTime;

                var sample = MediaStreamSample.CreateFromDirect3D11Surface(frame.Surface, timeStamp);
                args.Request.Sample = sample;

                // when called again (manually by us) complete the work
                // and reset members
                if (_def != null)
                {
                    _def.Complete();
                    _def = null;
                    _args = null;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          ...
        }
    }
    else
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

Another solution is to simply freeze the frames timestamp, so add these members:

```
private TimeSpan _pausedTimestamp;
public bool IsPaused { get; private set; }

public void Pause()
{
    IsPaused = true;
}

public void Resume()
{
    IsPaused = false;
}
```

And modify `OnMediaStreamSourceSampleRequested` methods like this (where I've put comments):

```
private void OnMediaStreamSourceSampleRequested(MediaStreamSource sender, MediaStreamSourceSampleRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    if (_isRecording && !_closed)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var frame = _frameGenerator.WaitForNewFrame())
            {
                if (frame == null)
                {
                    args.Request.Sample = null;
                    DisposeInternal();
                    return;
                }

                // if paused, "freeze" the timestamp
                TimeSpan timeStamp;
                if (IsPaused)
                {
                    timeStamp = _pausedTimestamp;
                }
                else
                {
                    timeStamp = frame.SystemRelativeTime;
                    _pausedTimestamp = timeStamp;
                }

                var sample = MediaStreamSample.CreateFromDirect3D11Surface(frame.Surface, timeStamp);
                args.Request.Sample = sample;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          ...
        }
    }
    else
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: second method doesn't work. Video file just gets corrupted and doesn't play. 

First method works fine but still *sometimes* video doesn't play. What could be issue?

Comment: Both work for me and I never get any corrupted file (HD 1080p 60 fps). But looking at the result, when resume happens, you have to wait few seconds before it takes effect.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by wait for few seconds after resume?

Comment: It depends on the player there may be a delay between the time when you resumed at recording time and the time when it visually resumes in the player